# How to change background image, with seek bar movement?

Tags: java, android, xml

In my app I want to show background changing from day to night when my seek bar on activity is changed.
I have made a new activity showing seek bar, which shows time. When "time" is in A.M., the background should be showing day, otherwise it should show night.

Comment: You can paste the code so any person can help you at the point your code is being stucked :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a minimal working example of what you have tried.

Comment: There is no tax on showing what you have done so far in SO

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done so far

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#ff00ff">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="@string/network_name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_15sp" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="0"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Size of Network"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seek1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="0"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Duration of Network"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seek2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Tanya, is this an answer or a supplement to your question, in the second case please edit your question and delete your supplement from the answer section.